# Alter the cost of products using phpmyadmin sql query

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, database, sql

What is the SQL query can i use in phpmyadmin to alter(update) the listed products cost in woocommerce.

EX: I want to add or subtract $100 from all the listed products.

Comment: that's not WP question specifically, you might ask that on Stackoverflow to get better help from DB/Mysql users.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a SQL query. You can do this programatically.

```
$price = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_price');
$price += 100; // use -= 100 to subtract
update_post_meta($product_id, '_price', $price);
update_post_meta($product_id, '_regular_price', $price);
```